# chrome.runtime.sendMessage receieves null response from background script

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I am receiving `null` response, when I use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` in contentScript to send a request to the `background` script and receive a response. I am using chrome version 83.0.4103.97.

content script.ts

```
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  // We only accept messages from this window to itself, no iframes allowed.
  if (event.source !== window) {
    return;
  }

  // Relay relevant messages only.
  if (event.data.type && relevantEventTypes.indexOf(event.data.type) > -1) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(event.data, (resp: any) => {
      console.log("In content script");
      console.log(resp);
    });
  }
}, false);
```

background.ts

```
const create = async (msg, sender: chrome.runtime.MessageSender) => {
    return {
        var1: "var1",
        var2: "var2"
    };
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    switch (msg.type) {
        case 'create':
            create(msg, sender).then(sendResponse);
            break;
        default:
            sendResponse(null);
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Your code explicitly returns `null` so your actual msg.type must be different from `create`. Use devtools to debug the code.

Comment: I verified it. msg.type value is `create`. Also, this code works fine on other older chrome versions (I am running that on a different machine, but both have ubuntu 18). Could it be an issue with specific chrome versions?

Comment: Did you verify it in the background script? Because the problem may be that your `event.data` is not sent correctly but rather as `{}` due to some reason that needs to be uncovered.

Comment: In my case, I was getting null in response because somewhere else, I had written `sendResponse()` which was always returning null response.